# shell script internal vs external arguments

Tags: shell, arguments

I inherited a shell script 'myScript.sh', that I want parametrize. 
Inside the script there is a function, like this:

```
function hmac_sha256 {
  key="$1"
  data="$2"
  printf "${data}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "${key}" | \
      sed 's/^.* //'
}
```

Now, when I want to call the overall script in my terminal I do

```
/.myScript arg1 arg2 etc
```

These args, to my limited knowledge, are by default represented by respective '$1', '$2', etc. I use these args elsewhere in the script, NOT as arguments for this specific function.

However, these very $1 and $2 are already in use in the function above.

The question is I think: how do I distinguish between 'external' and 'internal' arguments?

Comment: You can assign the shell script arguments to other variables at the beginning of the script, just like the function does for its own arguments.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That is what I do. So, '$1' has the value of the argument that I pass to the script, but will have a different value when it is passed to the function?

Comment: *"but will have a different value when it is passed to the function"* Maybe this is just phrased strangely. If you mean that `$1` will have a different value in the function than it has in the remainder of the script then the answer is yes. You have to think of them as two different variables (because they are).

Comment: @Felix Kling: that is what I meant. You might want to answer my question as such, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

Most portable way across different shells would be to assign script arguments to global variables.

```
ARG1="$1"
ARG2="$2"
echo "My arguments $ARG1 $ARG2"
```

There is also shortcut for this in most modern shells (at least bash, zsh, ksh) which have support for arrays. Be aware that strict POSIX shells don't have arrays, so this will not work in them. You can assign `$@` to array and access this array instead like this:

```
ARGV=("$@")
# arguments in ARGV array will be shifted - $1 on index 0, $2 on index 1, etc..
echo "My arguments ${ARGV[0]} ${ARGV[1]}"
```

At last, if you are ok with an unportable bash script, you can use BASH_ARGV array.

```
echo "My arguments ${BASH_ARGV[1]} ${BASH_ARGV[0]}"
```